# VBA error next but without for each

Tags: vba, foreach

Hi I find error when running this routine in VBA.

```
Sub interest()
    Dim newRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Range("D9").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select

    For Each cel In rng.Cells
     If cell.Value = "Cr" Then
     cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
     Else
     cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value * (-1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you describe the error?, more details could be useful

Answer (score 3):

You forgot an `End If` before `Next cel`

Answer (score 2):

**You didn't attributed anything to rng!** You only selected some range of the spreadsheet.
The code could be fixed like this:

```
...
    Range("D9").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set rng = Selection
...
```

Comment: Sub interest()
    Dim newRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Range("D9").Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
     Set rng = Selection
     
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
     If cell.Value = "Cr" Then
     cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
     Else
     cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value * (-1)
    Next
    
End Sub

Comment: i have put   Set rng = Selection, however error still appears.

Comment: @Drawin yes you should also replace `rng.Cells` with `rng` and there's also a typo in `cel`. BTW please provide the error statement if all this didn't work.

Comment: @DarwinChan, replace all `cell` with `cel`

Comment: While this is also an issue, it doesn't fix the original problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compile error because you aren't closing the `If`-block with **`End If`** (See iDevlop's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35057557/4600127)).
In VBA, you need to write `If` as follows:

```
If cell.Value = "Cr" Then
    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
Else
    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value * (-1)
End If
```

Only then you can finish the `For`-Loop with `Next`.

PS: As mentioned by Ehsan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35056041/4600127), you should assign some values to `rng`, or you will run into the next error at `rng.Cells`.

Comment: why just repeating other's answers ?

Comment: Because this answer not only makes the point way more clear, but also includes the other problem with `rng.Cells`. To be fair, I'll add the link to your answer as well.

Comment: The rng problem was already answered by Ehsan Abd, as you noticed.

Comment: Which is why i cited him, as well as i cited you. My intention was to give a comprehensive answer.